# MySQL - Clone a row and all its children

Tags: mysql

I have a table named **`users`**.
This table is linked to **`agendas`**, which is itself linked to **`events`**.

An agenda can have 0 or n event.

So now, what if I want to clone user #3 with all of his agendas and events, keeping all foreign keys up to date?

I know how to do that with multiple queries (SELECT then INSERT, get inserted_id and so on...), but I have no clue how to do that in a single query.

I also found how to copy the user's row, but not its children:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_users SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = 3;
UPDATE tmp_users SET userID = NULL;
INSERT INTO users SELECT * FROM tmp_users;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_users;
```

So if anyone got an idea, I 'm not a pro of mySQL and I don't event know if that's possible ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you're looking for something like this

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name, ...)
SELECT user_name, ...
  FROM users
 WHERE user_id = 3;

SET @last_user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO agendas (user_id, agenda_name, ...)
SELECT @last_user_id, agenda_name, ...
  FROM agendas
 WHERE user_id = 3;

INSERT INTO events (agenda_id, event_name, ...)
SELECT a3.agenda_id_new, e.event_name, ...
  FROM events e JOIN
(SELECT a1.agenda_id agenda_id_old, 
       a2.agenda_id agenda_id_new
  FROM
(SELECT agenda_id, @n := @n + 1 n 
   FROM agendas, (SELECT @n := 0) n 
  WHERE user_id = 3 ORDER BY agenda_id) a1 JOIN
(SELECT agenda_id, @m := @m + 1 m 
   FROM agendas, (SELECT @m := 0) m 
  WHERE user_id = @last_user_id ORDER BY agenda_id) a2 ON a1.n = a2.m) a3 
     ON e.agenda_id = a3.agenda_id_old;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/345cb9/2)**

*The assumption is that all tables have id columns (`user_id`, `agenda_id`, `event_id`) set to `auto_increment`*

And you can always to wrap it up into a stored procedure with an input parameter of a user being cloned.

Comment: @julien-l Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Eyh peter, thank you for your answer, I had not the time to try it for now (new priorities ^^) but I will be using it in the days coming, so I will keep you informed! Thanks again!

Comment: So, I just tried it with some modifications to fit to my database, and it worked just so fine... That's exactly what I wanted to do!
Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I got a problem... The query is working fine when I run it directly from phpmyadmin, but it seems like it's not working in a prepared statement with bind parameters. I print the query before executing it to see if there was an error, but no, it's still working in phpmyadmin. Do I have to separate each INSERT statement into separate queries? Is the problem coming from the loop where the number of bind parameters is not matching anymore? I don't really understand...

Comment: Well that was the problem, I could not run multiple INSERT into one prepared statement. I separated into multiple queries and replaced `SET @last_user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()` by `$stmt->insert_id` to get the inserted user_id